# Location specific events from facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, object, location

Is there a way to obtain the "event" (or for that matter any publicly available object) from  a particular area, say brazil using the facebook platform?
I understand that we need authentication to access data that are privacy protected. But events/pages are public right?(correct me if am wrong)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Search API to search for public objects in a certain area: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching